# "context" can not be used ChicagoBoss Template Tags

Tags: django, chicagoboss

After upgrading `ChicagoBoss` to latest version `(i.e.from 0.8.10 -> 0.8.14)`. I have been observing that the term `"context"` can not be used in any of the chicagoboss template tags.

Its giving syntax error :

eg.

```
{% if context == data.code %}
          <option selected>{{data.value1}}</option>
{% else %}
          <option selected>{{data.value2}}</option>
{% endif %}
```

### OR

```
{% url action="some_action" context=data.val %}
```

And same error thrown for these template tags :

```
Unhandled Error: error:{case_clause,{ok,[{"src/view/x_return/form_12.html",
                         [{{88,15},
                           erlydtl_parser,
                           ["syntax error before: ",["\"context\""]]}]}]}} Stacktrace: [{boss_web_controller_render,render_view,5,[{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller_render.erl"},{line,217}]},{boss_web_controller,execute_action_inner,9,[{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller.erl"},{line,290}]},{boss_web_controller_handle_request,process_dynamic_request,5,[{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller_handle_request.erl"},{line,254}]},{boss_web_controller_handle_request,process_request,5,[{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller_handle_request.erl"},{line,240}]},{boss_web_controller_handle_request,set_timer,8,[{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller_handle_request.erl"},{line,160}]},{boss_web_controller_handle_request,build_dynamic_response,5,[{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller_handle_request.erl"},{line,129}]},{boss_web_controller_handle_request,handle_request,4,[{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller_handle_request.erl"},{line,26}]},{mochicow_upgrade,upgrade,4,[{file,"src/mochicow_upgrade.erl"},{line,72}]}]
```

It works pretty fine when I change `"context"` to `"cntxt"` or anything other than `context`.

As you may know that `ChicagoBoss` tags is just similar to `Django` template tags. Since I followed ChicagoBoss as well as Django documentation but I could not see any documentation that `"context"` is keyword or any reserved term.

- Any django developer does have any idea about it?
- Does it occur in Django templates also?

**Note** - I do have many files containing `"context"` used in template tags. Since not a good idea to update each file to change the term manually.

- Also raised an issue at [Github - ChicagoBoss Issues](https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/ChicagoBoss/issues/563)

Comment: ChicagoBoss  is not a django copy.  It has nothing common with django, and it doesnt use django in any way.  ChicagoBoss   is a erlang framework. The only common thing that it use django style templates  , but it still not the same and it has zero common code with django.

Comment: @Aldarund - Sorry, I was wrong. Thanks for correcting me. Do you know the reason of the bug I'm facing?

Comment: Sry, no, i only know python\django, but not chicagoboss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context` changed bing a reserved keyword in erlydtl (the  Erlang implementation of the Django Template Language) in version 0.9.4, see:
https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl/releases/tag/0.9.4

So when you updated your `ChicagoBoss`, as a dependency you probably pulled a erlydtl versoin >= 0.9.4

You could recompile ChicagoBoss after configuring a lower tag version of erlydtl in the rebar.config in the root directory of your ChicagoBoss. As an example, if you want version 0.9.3, put:

> {erlydtl, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl.git", {tag, "0.9.3"}}}

Comment: Yeah, I had got the answer from the same documentation.
Thanks for your efforts!!

Comment: Nice! :) I found your question because of a similar problem I faced, so I thought summing it up might help other, too. Best,